# How to send selected option with Django and Ajax?

Tags: python, django, ajax

i have a problem about send or save my selected option to database. I have tried all the ways I know to run this program, but always the selected option is not saved.
I have removed the line of code I was trying to solve this problem so that you guys can come up with a solution in your own way. if you guys need more detailed code just let me know. hope you can understand what I'm saying

my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my forms.py:

```
class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
        required=False
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'category','thumbnail']
```

my views.py:

```
def gallery_list_and_create(request):
    form = GalleryForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if(request.user.is_authenticated):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        gallery_user = user.gallery_set.all()
        if(is_ajax(request=request)):
            if(form.is_valid()):
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.author = user
                instance.save()
                return JsonResponse({
                    'id': instance.id,
                    'title': instance.title,
                    'description': instance.description,
                    # 'category': [category.category for category in instance.category.all()],
                    'thumbnail': instance.thumbnail.url,
                    'slug': instance.slug,
                    'author': instance.author.username,
                    'since': instance.updated_timesince,

                })
        
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'gallery': gallery_user,
        }
    
        return render(request, 'Post/index.html', context)
    return render(request, 'Post/index.html')
```

my js file:

```
postForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf[0].value)
    fd.append('title', titleID.value)
    fd.append('description', descriptionID.value.length > 0 ? descriptionID.value : "")
    **'how to append category'?**
    fd.append('thumbnail', thumbnailID.files[0])
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of using `commit=False`: it prevents saving the many-to-many field, since this is done *after* you created object:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.author = user
    instance = form.save()  # saves object and m2m
    return JsonResponse({})  # return data
```

Comment: what is the next step?